# Qt and C++ class giving me an error

Tags: c++, qt

what am I doing wrong?

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "fileoperations.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
class FileOperations;
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    FileOperations FileController;

private slots:
    void on_OpenButton_clicked();
    void on_SaveButton_clicked();
    void on_EncodeButton_clicked();
    void on_DecodeButton_clicked();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

When i try to compile and run the program, it says:

```
g:\ke\c++ projects\projects\qt\shitlencoder\mainwindow.h:18: error: C2079: 'MainWindow::FileController' uses undefined class 'FileOperations'
```

Here's the strange thing, if I change 'FileOperations FileController;' to 'FileOperations *FileController;'(Obviously this compiles wrongly, because the rest of my codes that you can't see havn't been adapted to '->' instead of '.')
Then if I change it back to 'FileOperations FileController;' it lets me compile the program once (And it works fine), then it has the error the next time I try to compile it.

I'm using Qt 5.0.

fileoperations.h:

```
#ifndef FILEOPERATIONS_H
#define FILEOPERATIONS_H
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class FileOperations
{
public:
    FileOperations();
    void SetInputFile(QString x);
    void SetOutputFile(QString x);
    void EncryptAndSave(Ui::MainWindow *NUI);
    void DecryptAndSave(Ui::MainWindow *NUI);
    void createid(int id, int id2);
    int GetCFuncion();
    void SetCFuncion(int x);
    long long Get_Size(string filename);
    bool Get_Toobig(string path);
    //DWORD WINAPI Thread_no_1();
private:
    string InputFilename;
    string OutputFilename;
    int CFuncion;//CurrentFunction;
    vector<int> conbyte1;
    vector<int> conbyte2;
    vector<int> opbyte1;
    vector<int> opbyte2;
    vector<int> passwordbytes;
};

#endif // FILEOPERATIONS_H
```

Comment: How does `fileoperations.h` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are holding a `FileOperations` object in your class, you need the full class declaration. This means you have to include the header, you cannot simply forward declare the class like you are doing now. If you hold only a pointer, and do not have any code in your header that attempts to dereference the pointer, then the forward declaration is enough.

**EDIT** You have a cyclical include. You are including `mainwindow.h` in `fileoperations.h`. You can fix if by removing that include completely.

Comment: But `fileoperations.h` **is** included?

Comment: @Andreas well, does `fileoperations.h` have the class declaration? If so, OP should state it. And it is probably broken.

Comment: There, i put the fileoperations.h class in.

Comment: There you go. You re-include "mainwindow.h" in fileoperations.h - thus, the compiler sees mainwindow.h first and does not know anything about FileOperations

Comment: Thankyou, i really need to learn how the order of things work :)
I've only been learning C++ properly for 3 days..

Comment: As rule of thumb, avoid unnecessary #includes in include files - use forward declarations when possible (means, when only pointers or references to a particular class are used)

Answer (score 3):

I assume that, in your .cpp file, you are using

```
#include "fileoperations.h"
```

Then, in `fileoperations.h`, you are including `mainwindow.h` which again includes `fileoperations.h` which is basically correct, since you are using a `FileOperations` object as parameter. But, due to the guards, `class FileOperations` is not seen by the compiler this time, hence `FileOperations` is unknown when used as parameter in your method. You need to break this dependency:

In `fileoperations.h`, use a forward declaration for `Ui::MainWindow` and remove the `#include "mainwindow.h"`:

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have circular include issue,  mainwindow.h and fileoperations.h include each other, try to remove below line from `fileoperations.h`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
```